# For TableViewController and a drill-down UI decision

Tags: iphone, ios

not as much of a programming question as a design question...

I have a tableviewcontroller and I want to show a list of Artists and Albums.

Easy enough, but I want to show a "detail" page for both the Artist and Albums.

With a hierarchy of (Artist->Album), you select an Artist and then the list of Albums are displayed.  Then you can select Album details.

But, I also want to also be able to see Artist details.

So, I had 2 ideas and wanted to get some suggestions.

1. On the Album details, include a button/link/something and say "show Artist details".  I don't like this too much though...
2. Don't use a hierarchy and have a long list of:
   (Sorry can't get the formatting correct here:)
   LINE1: Artist ABC 
   LINE2: Album 123 by Artist ABC
   LINE3: Album 234 by Artist ABC 
   LINE4: etc.

This gets a bit long, but kinda like it better.

Or Three:  Use #2 idea, but indent the Album text a bit to show that they are related to the parent.

In the apps that I have, I haven't seen a common UI for this...any suggestions?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea would be to use the usual UINavigationViewController hierarchy and add one of these typical ⓘ-info-buttons to the right side of each artist/album cell.
Now when you are in the Artists list, show the detail page just when the user taps that ⓘ and show the list of an Artist's albums when the user taps anywhere else in a cell.

Another possibility would be to show an UIBarButton for the Artist's details in your UINavigationItem of the artist's albums list.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking of a button as well.  I might use the (i) or I might use the image that I already have in the cell and turn it into a button...